# npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.4: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, npm-install

I keep getting this npm warning after running `npm install`. I have deleted and reinstalled npm. Nothing seems to work.

```
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.4: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

up to date, audited 2107 packages in 26s

94 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

68 vulnerabilities (14 low, 18 moderate, 32 high, 4 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with npm, but with your project. It requires (possibly indirectly), fsevents@1.2.4, which is deprecated. You'll need to update your project to require a newer version, e.g.:

```
"fsevent": "^2.3.2"
```

and of course, update your project to work with this version.

Comment: How would I go about updating fsevents, I have tried using brew and npm.

Comment: You need to update your package.json

Comment: I have tried npm upgrade, it ran without any errors or warnings but when using the npm i, it gives me the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

For new people facing this issue:

`fsevents` is a low-level library, most of the time it is an optional dependency of another package you might have in your `package.json`, since it's a [MacOS library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents)

Steps to fix it:

`yarn why fsevents` This will tell you which package is using `fsevents`. Depending on your yarn version you might need to keep doing `yarn why` to find the root package.

When you find it:

`yarn update {ROOT_LEVEL_PACKAGE}`

Yes, that will update all the dependencies for that package, but it will fix the issue with `fsevents` or any other package you are having issues with

Answer (score -1):

first try to reset npm cache

```bash
npm cache clean --force
```

then retry to install npm packages

if nothing happens, try `npm install --no-optional` or `npm install --force`

hope that works

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, outputs the same warning.